# Keep address of inserted element in vector (c++)

Tags: c++, vector

Say I have a shared `vector` of `int` between several objects:

```
vector <int> list;
```

Each object can add more elements into it:

```
list.push_back(someint);
```

I would like these objects to be able to delete the elements them put inside, but I can't know the position because of the other object actions.
Also if I keep the element address it will just correspond to the position in the list which will change so I don't know.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a `std::vector` and you add an element. Then you erase and add one or more other elements, and finally you need to erase the original element?

`std::vector` is not really suited for that. Why not use a `std::list` instead? With a `std::list`, you can [`insert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) an element and will get an iterator to the newly inserted element. Unlike with `std::vector`, a `std::list` iterator will stay valid even if other elements are later added or removed.